# WCF Callbacks on Remote Computers within Same Network

Tags: wcf, networking, callback

I have a WCF client & service, where service (which is hosted inside a console app) calls back to client using ever so standard `WSDualHttpBinding` with `WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None`. It's all fine and dandy when hosted on a local machine, but as soon as I move service to a computer other than my local machine (but on the same network), client cannot connect to the service anymore.

MEX is working fine, I can get hold of WSDL and all that. After capturing outbound traffic with Fiddler, here's what I got:

```
POST /chinchillin HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: 192.168.0.98:8080
Content-Length: 916
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:aa317faa-f32e-4cbc-a6a3-5fdbc9f80fe6</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://agogolev.ad.alponline.ru/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/f423a1ae-573a-4c14-9a64-c4ed26fc6366/3069625c-d37a-4de2-8f92-e078b51f01d5</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://192.168.0.98:8080/chinchillin</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <CreateSequence xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm">
      <AcksTo>
        <a:Address>http://agogolev.ad.alponline.ru/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/f423a1ae-573a-4c14-9a64-c4ed26fc6366/3069625c-d37a-4de2-8f92-e078b51f01d5</a:Address>
      </AcksTo>
      <Offer>
        <Identifier>urn:uuid:7d198ab8-4fed-4f62-a76b-6e2ae2a13dda</Identifier>
      </Offer>
    </CreateSequence>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2010 08:41:48 GMT
```

I tried turning off firewalls on both machines, registered URL ACL with `netsh -c http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/chinchillin user=domain\user`. None of this helped.

How can I get callbacks to work in this scenario?

Comment: Is there a possibility you have NAT between client and service? Have you tried using NetTcpBinding for duplex messaging?

Comment: @Dmitry No, no NAT whatsoever

Comment: Have you enabled logging and looked through the service logs?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to create a trivial service exposing just one or two methods and see if you can get it to work across the network.  If not, then maybe there IS a network issue, if you can, then you might be able to work your way up to figuring out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured. The server I moved the service part of my app to was not inside an AD domain and could not resolve `http://agogolev.ad.alponline.ru`.